# Jersey Restful dependency version

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have an application which uses the following **Jersey restful** web services dependency (Maven):

```
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
```

And its jar (**jersey-server-2.7.jar**) is actually downloaded (using Maven). However, when I check for this very same dependency in Maven, it shows that the most recently version is **2.17** from 29-Jun-2015. How can this be possible ? The same situation I have for **jersey-client-2.7.jar**...

Any hints welcome ! Thanks in advance

Comment: It means your project still using old `version`. And maven will not restrict you to use older versions. You can use any version you want  and more recent is `2.19`. Have a look at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client

Comment: Your question is unclear. Or it is not clear what your confusion is.

Answer (score 1):

They used digits after the dot  in the version to specify Java to compile the library (jersey 2.6 coresponds Java 6). It was until java 7 was released (the same for jersey 1.X). Then they kept using ascending numeration. in you case version 2.7 older then 2.17 because 17 >7.

Comment: Roman, Thanks for your comment ! I had not realized what you mention.